# Get value f(x) declared in the tikz environment

Tags: tikz-pgf, environments, coordinates

I've declared my f(x) in the tikzpicture environment, and tikz draws the graph of it. OK, now I want mark a point on the plot of my function.

I thought, I could \coordinate point M at (x, myrandomf(x)) and then do what I want with M. For example, make small circle there.

But I get an error "unknown function 'x'" here:

```
\coordinate (M) at (3, myrandomf(3));
```

How can I fix it?

The whole code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[
          declare function ={ myrandomf(\x) = 5 + (x-4)^3/10 - x^2/10; 
                            },
        ]
          \begin{axis}[
              axis lines = middle,
              axis line style = {-Latex[round],very thick},
              enlargelimits = true,
              xlabel = {$x$}, 
              ylabel = {$f(x)$}, 
              xmin = -1,
              ymin = -1,
              xmax = 10,
              ymax = 10,
              domain = -1:10,
              xtick = \empty,
              ytick = \empty,
              extra x ticks={0},
              xlabel style={below right},
              ylabel style={above left},
              x tick label style={below right},
              samples = 100
          ]
            \addplot[very thick, color=red] {myrandomf(x)};
            \coordinate (O) at (0, 0);
            \coordinate (M) at (3, myrandomf(3));
            % \filldraw (M) circle[radius=1.5pt];
          \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome. Please give a fully compilable code.

Comment: Try `(3, {myrandomf(3)})`. You should hide the internal parenthesis from the coordinate parser...

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to what Rmano mentioned in a comment, you need to use `\x` not `x` all places in the declaration of the function. So you have

```
declare function ={ myrandomf(\x) = 5 + (\x-4)^3/10 - \x^2/10; },
```

and later

```
\coordinate (M) at (3, {myrandomf(3)});
```

As a sidenote, if all you want is to add dots at some points on the graph, you can do e.g. `\addplot [only marks, samples at={3}] {myrandomf(x)};`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
          declare function ={ myrandomf(\x) = 5 + (\x-4)^3/10 - \x^2/10; 
                            },
        ]
          \begin{axis}[
              axis lines = middle,
              axis line style = {-Latex[round],very thick},
              enlargelimits = true,
              xlabel = {$x$}, 
              ylabel = {$f(x)$}, 
              xmin = -1,
              ymin = -1,
              xmax = 10,
              ymax = 10,
              domain = -1:10,
              xtick = \empty,
              ytick = \empty,
              extra x ticks={0},
              xlabel style={below right},
              ylabel style={above left},
              x tick label style={below right},
              samples = 100
          ]
            \addplot[very thick, color=red] {myrandomf(x)};
            
%            \addplot [only marks, samples at={3}] {myrandomf(x)};
            
            \coordinate (O) at (0, 0);
            \coordinate (M) at (3, {myrandomf(3)});
            \filldraw (M) circle[radius=1.5pt];
          \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip with samples! 

"...you need to use \x not x all places in the declaration of the function" - but why then did tex understand me and compile the code with x not \x?

Comment: @Allok I think in `\addplot` it doesn't matter because pgfplots by default defines an `x` variable for its macros. But when using TikZ macros like `\coordinate` that definition isn't available.